# Scroll div inside td in fixed height table

Tags: html, css

The issue: https://jsfiddle.net/sjefb/xctr0zve/1/

```
<div style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid red">
  <table border="1" id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td id="td1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td2">
        <div>
          testtest
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td3">
        <div id="div1">
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
          <div>
            test
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #table1 {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #td1 {
      height: 40vh;
      width:100%;
      min-height: 240px;
    }

    #td2 {}

    #td3 {
      height: 60%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #div1 {
      overflow: auto;
      height: 180px;
      /*works, not what I want*/
      height: 100%;
      display:block;
      /* doesn't work*/
    }
```

I'd like the lines in td3 to scroll, and the table not to exceed the red area. The pages must be readable on all screen formats, so everything has to be done using percentages. I tried and puffed and puffed, but the table still grows too large.

Do you have any tips for me? Thanks!

UPDATE

This is what I get at the moment:
[image: table too high]

but I want to see this:
[image: intended layout]

Comment: Any more information or my answer fixed it ?

Comment: in your jsfiddle and my jsfiddle this is what you get. There is no problem here

Comment: No it isn't. i do not want to use the line that sets the height of td3 to a fixed size. See the original fiddle.

Comment: but how do you think that you can get this without setting a height for that div ?

Comment: I don't know... That's why I asked my question:-) I want it to be a relative height, based on the size of div1. I cannot calculate the height of td3, it must be automatically set. The height of div1 isn't fixed either, in my real problem, but for the sake of this example I set it to 500px.

Comment: check my updated jsfiddle in the answer. I removed the height from the td3 so it is auto now

Comment: Nope, sorry. There are many lines that are visible under the red div1. I need the div inside td3 to scroll, nothing else, and no lines visible underneath the red area. See the 2nd image above: a scroll-bar at the right and only 9 of the 14 lines or so visible. I really don't know if it can be accomplished at all.

Comment: i think that you are looking to another jsfiddle because i can't see those lines that are visible under the red div1. check screenshot http://prntscr.com/c71vvl

Comment: Ah, I see. Just reduce the CSS area to a minimum.

Comment: i reduced to minimum and it's still working great.

Comment: Darn, more info: I have a 1920x1080 window, maximized. Then set the height of the very first div to 400px instead of 500.

Comment: it will work at any size. it has overflow:scroll so there is no way that it's outside of that div. send me screenshots of my jsfiddle that is showing not correctly

Comment: http://prnt.sc/c721xw

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xctr0zve/5/ check now

Comment: Better, a lot! So it can't handle the 40vh correctly? That's a shame, but I can probably use it as a percentage. Which isn't the same of course. Thanks, really!  If you update your answer below accordingly, I'll accept it.

Comment: it can't handle because when the height is more than 1200 than 40vh are more than 500px so that's why there was a problem with that. I updated the jsfiddle in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121209/discussion-between-edisoni-1337-and-d-bugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xctr0zve/6/)

```
#div1 {
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change much. Okay, it makes the scroll-bar visible, but that's all. But what I want to achieve you can see when you remove the height: 100% in div1. I moved the comments in the CSS a little, in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sjefb/xctr0zve/3/ , to make it somewhat clearer.

Comment: By the way, I'm using FF48.

Comment: you said that you want the lines in td3 to scroll, and the table not to exceed the red area. i think that this is fixed in this jsfiddle. I am not understanding what else you want to fix

Comment: So I shouldn't have used 40vh... Apparently it cannot be handled correctly by the browsers I use. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Comment: Pls reopen the chat.